# Recursion in C++: Solving proofs using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

In a lab for my discrete mathematics class we are solving proofs
within programs. The exhaustive method wasn't too hard, but I am
having some difficulty with recursion. The question is as follows:

> "Write a program that prompts users to input a positive integer n, then print out an in the console that is given by:
>
> a subscript n = (-1)^n · √n · a subscript(n-1); a subscript(1) = 2.

In my function `CalcAn` whenever `n` is equal to `2`, it should return `2`. But the program  keeps stopping. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <cstdlib>  // For several general-purpose functions
#include <fstream>  // For file handling
#include <iomanip>  // For formatted output
#include <iostream> // For cin, cout, and system
#include <string>   // For string data type
#include<cmath>     // for exponent and square root functions
using namespace std;

double CalcAn(int n)
{
    if ((n - 1) == 1)
        return 2.0;
    else
        return pow(-1, n) * sqrt(n) * CalcAn(n - 1);
}

int main(){

    int n;
    double an;

    cout << "Please enter a positive integer: ";

    cin >> n;

    while (n <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Error: Invalid input, please try again: ";
        cin >> n;
    }

    an = pow(-1, n) * sqrt(n) * CalcAn(n - 1);

    cout << endl << an << endl << endl;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: as a side note, `pow(-1,n)` is a pessimization, just do `(n%2?-1:1)` ...

Comment: What does "stopping"? Does it crash? Do you get an error? If you're running on Windows are you sure it doesn't just exit quickly?

Comment: @patatahooligan I am running on Xcode on Mac. The build would succeed and after I input an integer it would wait for about 5 seconds then stop running and show (LLdb) in my output.

Comment: Your recursion stops only when `n-1 == 1`, which is the same as `n == 2`. You call your function with `CalcAn(n-1)`. If your input is `2`, then you call `CalcAn(1)` which proceeds to recurse until  `n == 2`, which won't happen before the stack overflows..

Answer (score 3):

If you input 2, you will pass 1 to `CalcAn`, and that will most likely terminate with an error when the stack overflows.

If you don't divide the computation between `CalcAn` and `main`, and use the same base case as the definition, you get a very straightforward translation that should work:

```
double CalcAn(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 2.0;
    else
        return pow(-1, n) * sqrt(n) * CalcAn(n - 1);
}

int main(){    
    int n;
    double an;    
    cout << "Please enter a positive integer: ";    
    cin >> n;    
    while (n <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Error: Invalid input, please try again: ";
        cin >> n;
    }    
    an = CalcAn(n);    
    cout << endl << an << endl << endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I honestly don't know why I had an iteration outside of the `CalcAn` , I was looking at examples from my textbook trying to emulate what they did. That makes a lot more sense to set `an = CalcAN(n);` Thank you.